# Getting 'cant read if of null'

Tags: javascript

Here is html:

```
<div class="nama" id="xxx"></div>
```

And javascript :

```
var div = document.getElementById('xxx');
alert(div.id)
```

Why i am getting mistake?Looks like fine for me

Comment: i shoud use window.onload?

Answer (score 1):

The element was not found.

Most probably because this code was ran before that part of the DOM was ready.

Try placing your code below where the HTML is defined.

Comment: Working now 
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
window.onload = function() {
    var div = document.getElementById('xxx');
    alert(div.id)
};
```